# Ubuntu 22.04 Does not Boot - Problem Blacklisting hash(-13)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04

I have Windows 11 on 240 GB SATA SSD and Ubuntu 20.04 on 500 GB NvME SSD. I flashed an USB with official Ubuntu 22.04.03 iso file.

I could not boot. I got `Problem blacklisting hash error`. I have waited about 1 hour and nothing changed.

[image: error_screenshot]